# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error p0=task

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have a simple angular code with wont run due to this error;
ive add the angular-router file the server found it but it keeps giving me this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=task&p1=Error%3A%20…0Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:43
    at p (angular.min.js:8)
    at g (angular.min.js:42)
    at gb (angular.min.js:46)
    at c (angular.min.js:22)
    at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
    at xe (angular.min.js:21)
    at angular.min.js:333
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

my view code is

```
<html >
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="task" ng-init="first = 1;">
        <h1>Task List</h1>

        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            <span>Values: {{first}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="first" />
        </div>



        <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
         <script src="angular/app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

my app.js code

```
var task = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
task.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.first = 1;
});
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly states:

> Failed to instantiate module **task** due to:
>   Error: …0Uc (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:22:332)

The module name needs to match the name used in the `ng-app` directive:

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-init="first = 1;">
```

```
//var task = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
var task = angular.module('task', ['ngRoute']);
task.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.first = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Think you might need to rewrite that app.js code slightly:

```
task.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.first = 1;
}]);
```

Why initialise first here in the controller when you're also doing it in the template, btw? Was there a reason?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do like this

```
var task = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
task.controller('ctrl', taskCtrl);

function taskCtrl($scope){
 // your logic here
}
```

Also move your ng-app tag to separate div and below it put JS script tags

Comment: Thank you for the optimization ;)